# Почему при модульном тестировании изолируют зависимости?

Tags: тестирование, юнит-тесты

Является ли обращение к БД напрямую из тестов плохим тоном? Или это частный случай тестирования, когда нет необходимости проверять правильность добавления и удаления данных в базу и из базы?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

В модульных тестах это не просто "плохой тон" - это недопустимо.

По хорошему, при модульном тестировании должны выполнятся все эти условия:

1. Каждый тест должен проверять строго только одну теорию о поведении модуля
2. Тестируемый класс должен быть изолирован от любых зависимостей - в том числе и от классов с которыми он работает(слава IoC!). И уж тем более, не должно присутствовать внепроектных зависимостей, таких как базы данных, время, сетевое и межпроцессное взаимодействие. Все зависимости при этом заменяют написанными вручную, либо автоматически сгенерированными заглушками.
3. Тест должен никогда не выполнятся более одной секунды. Чем меньше времени выполняется каждый тест - тем лучше, т.к. иначе разработчикам будет просто лениво ждать выполнения всех тестов при каждом перестроении проекта, и из-за этого от модульного тестирования со временем откажутся.

Использовать реальные зависимости нельзя из-за параллельной природы модульных тестов. Когда у вас в тестовом проекте появится больше одного теста с реальными зависимостями, между ними обязательно начнутся конфликты и ошибки взаимодействия.

Скажем, у вас в базе есть таблица. В одном тесте вы из неё удаляете строки, во втором добавляете, а в третьем получаете. Да, вы можете в конце каждого теста возвращать эту таблицу в исходное состояние, однако в модульных тестах вам никто вам не гарантирует, что в момент получения из таблицы строк третьим тестом, первый тест нужные строки не удалит - сущий хаос.

Хотите тестировать живую базу, живые зависимости - делайте это в **интеграционных** и/или **функциональных** тестах.

**Интеграционные тесты** - по сути, те же самые модульные тесты, в которых используются реальные зависимости, и которые выполняются не параллельно, а поочередно, в одной строгой последовательности. В отличии от модульных тестов, их цель - протестировать поведение модулей в составе единой системы.

Для них используют практически те же самые инструменты, что и для модульного тестирования. В проектах, использующих IoC-контейнеры, порой интеграционные и модульные тесты имеют общий код тестов - при интеграционном тестировании создают тестовое окружение(в чистую систему ставят нужные пакеты/приложения, изменяют необходимые настройки, развертывают базы данных), в IoC-контейнере заменяют заглушки реальными зависимостями, после чего выполняют тесты в нужной последовательности.

Наиболее полезны интеграционные тесты при тестировании "невидимой" пользователю части проекта(бекенду).

**Функциональные тесты** - имитируют действия реального человека, работающего с программным продуктом.

При таком тестировании, на тестовых серверах/устройствах разворачивается полноценная, рабочая версия проекта, ничем не отличающаяся от той, с которой работают пользователи. Тесты загружают сайт проекта в браузере или запускают приложение на ПК/мобильных устройствах, и, к примеру, щелкают на кнопки, вводят текст, перетаскивают элементы интерфейса, и т.д.

Таким образом проверяется соответствие внешнего поведения приложения тому, которое пользователь ждет от приложение, ну и корректность этого поведения(скажем - верно ли отображается html-страничка в десятке разных браузеров на разных платформах, да работают ли на них все заявленные функции?).

Их выгодно использовать при наличии в проекте сложного и функционального пользовательского интерфейса(фронтенда).

Comment: А чем отличается интеграционные, функциональныe и модульные тесты?

Comment: У меня тот же вопрос)

Comment: @koks_rs, добавил в ответ )

Comment: @klutch1991, дописал )

Comment: @SergeyRufanov, если я правильно понял, то если я в своём unit-тест проекте заменю заглушку FakeDBContext  реальным контекстом, то этот проект уже будет содержать т.н. "интеграционный" тест? Или же для этого необходимо использовать другой фреймворк, тип проекта?

Comment: @klutch1991, у вас получится тестовый проект со смешанными типами тестов. Что не есть хорошо. Во первых - конфликты между параллельно выполняющимися тестами с реальными зависимостями(почему это плохо - только что добавил в свой ответ). А во первых, реальные зависимости сильно замедлят выполнение тестов разработчиками при построении проекта.

Comment: @klutch1991, Менять инструменты не нужно - просто отделите такие тесты в отдельный проект, да заставьте используемый фреймворк запускать находящиеся в этом проекте тесты в нужной вам последовательности. В MS Test(встроенный в Visual Studio), это делается через Test List'ы. В случае с NUnit, и многими другими тестовыми фреймворками - просто пишут консольное приложение, в котором используя API тестового фреймворка, последовательно запускают тесты.

Comment: @SergeyRufanov, то есть все тесты, объединённые в один плейлист, будут выполняться параллельно? и Сами плейлисты будут выполняться один за другим?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33095/discussion-between-klutch1991-and-sergey-rufanov).

Comment: @klutch1991, последовательно, а не параллельно :) Да, именно так - тест за тестом, плейлист за плейлистом ) Без конфликтов, и с общим состоянием системы. К примеру, в с той же таблицой БД - можно спокойно занести в неё запись из одного теста, и тут-же использовать эту запись в следующем. В модульных тестах так сделать нельзя.